# How do I alias a template specialization?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, decltype

I have a type `T` that has a member function `fn` with a return type `RT`.
I have a template that takes `T` and `RT` as parameters.  I'd like to alias this template class so that my code isn't so ugly and hard to read.  How would I accomplish that?

```
template <typename X, typename Y>
struct I
{};

struct T
{
  int& fn(int);
};
```

So I want to alias this or something like this type so I can write a function like this:

```
template <typename C>
I< typename std::remove_reference<std::decltype(std::declval(C).fn(0))>::type, C> fn(C& c)
{
  return I< typename std::remove_reference<std::decltype(std::declval(C).fn(0))>::type, C>();
}
```

But with less mess. I've not used `std::decltype` before, so I'm not even sure if I'm using it right as I was getting errors.

I was thinking about using a function like that and doing a decltype on it, but I was having some difficulty with it and I'd like it to look cleaner too.

Comment: [like this one?](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7fbad782592aa57b)

Comment: yes. post it as an answer and I'll mark it as answered.

Comment: Oh wait.  It didn't work when instantiated.  [See here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3efd2d12eeaeff1f).

Comment: because you messed the order of parameters and their declaration, [see here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1ab23ec9b2c514f2)

Comment: @PiotrS. Oh, ok, but I've tried the same code in VS 2013 and it fails saying: `error C2036: 'I<remove_reference<unknown-type>::type,T>' : unknown size` for the line that calls `fn()` in `main()`

Comment: looks like a problem with VS

Comment: That's fine.  My workaround is to defer the `remove_reference` to the constructor of `I`.  Thanks. EDIT: Or I could use the helper function. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`decltype()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) is a built-in *operator*, not a function from the `std` namespace like `std::declval<T>()`.

If you want to shorten the syntax with an alias template, you can declare one as shown below:

```
#include <type_traits>    

template <typename C>
using IT = I<C, typename std::remove_reference<decltype(std::declval<C&>().fn(0))>::type>;

template <typename C>
IT<C> fn(C& c)
{
  return IT<C>(&c, c.fn(1));
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1ab23ec9b2c514f2)

---

Since the above code fails to compile successfully in VC++ for an unknown reason, you can instead create an alias template that queries the result type of a helper function that you already have:

```
template <typename C>
I<C, typename std::remove_reference<decltype(std::declval<C&>().fn(0))>::type> test();

template <typename C>
using IT = decltype(test<C>());

template <typename C>
IT<C> fn(C& c)
{
  return IT<C>(&c, c.fn(1));
}
```

[**DEMO 2**](http://rextester.com/EIWFQ59568)

Comment: Oh wait.  It didn't work when instantiated.  [See here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3efd2d12eeaeff1f).